# How do I transfer encrypted stored procedures from online DB to local?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, encryption

Been trying for over two weeks to backup / copy a database and script my stored procedures from a web-hosted SQL Server (2008) to a local installation (2008).

Problem is: I can't copy the encrypted ones. I know, it totally defeats the purpose of encryption to be able to get the actual data, but I was wondering... In our case, the guy who developed the database vanished 2 years ago and left everyone at the company with no "open" - without encryption - backups of the encrypted SPs. I am the "new" guy and can't figure out how to get to know these SPs.

Well, the message I get when trying to copy them using Script Wizard is a bit obvious:

> Property TextHeader is not available for StoredProcedure
>    '[dbo].[SP_CALC_PT_TV]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may
>    not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  **The text is encrypted.**
>    (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I've tried so far, without success:

- accessing them through Management Studio ('modify' option is greyed-out and scripting does not work)
- using the hosts provider own solution (web-based) to access the SPs
- using a third-party app to decrypt them (not enough privileges to run some of the commands)

Surely, I can just do them all again (about 45 SPs) from scratch, but I'd have to guess what the contents were and, you know...

I'd appreciate ANY help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the ability to restore a backup of the database to a local SQL Server install? If so, then try any of a number of decrypters I've found like the one here: http://www.elitude.net/

Comment: @JustinStolle: Looks like you could post that as an answer

Comment: @Andomar I hesitated because the OP seems to only be trying solutions in the hosted environment.

Comment: @Andomar @JustinStolle That's actually an answer but it may not apply to others as the host provider must perform a database dump somewhere where you can grab it by FTP or other download means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to restore a backup of the hosted database to a local installation of SQL Server, you could then try any number of decrypters I've found like the one here: http://www.elitude.net/

Comment: Thank you very much. We were technically able to do that, but we had not **thought** of that. Thanks.

Comment: Very good. I know from experience that the simplest of solutions can sometimes be the most elusive.