# How do I view the definition for a stored procedure that cannot be modified in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to view a stored procedure that resides in a database running in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have found the stored procedure under `[dbName] > Programmability > Stored Procedures > dbo.[sprocName]` but it has a little padlock icon next to it and when I right click on it to modify it, the modify option is grayed out.

I then tried to access the definition by querying object in the database like this:

```
use [dbName];
select * from sys.sql_modules
where definition LIKE '%[sprocName]%'
```

This does not yield the definition for the desired stored procedure, but the query does work for stored procedures that I can already modify.

How do I view the definition of this stored procedure without gaining modify privileges?

### Update

It appears that the Sproc is in fact encrypted based on this error message:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Script failed for StoredProcedure 'dbo.[sprocName]'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Property TextHeader is not available for StoredProcedure '[dbo].[sprocName]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  
    The text is encrypted. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stored procedure with a padlock icon in SQL 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027513/what-is-a-stored-procedure-with-a-padlock-icon-in-sql-2005)

Comment: Try this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith - While I acknowledge that there is relevant information in the question you specified, my question is different from that user's.

Comment: @quakkels - Yes sorry I agree. To view the definition without gaining modify privileges within SQL Server you will need to be granted the [`VIEW DEFINITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808(v=sql.105).aspx) permission.

Comment: After trying some of the solutions in the link posted by @liebs19, I can confirm the Sproc is encrypted based on the error messages I received.

Comment: Try this for decrypting it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443032/how-do-i-transfer-encrypted-stored-procedures-from-online-db-to-local

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you will need to have all the necessary permissions (SA basically) but here is a site that you should be able to follow to fix the problem.

http://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/03/07/decrypting-encrypted-stored-procedures-views-functions-in-sql-server-20052008-r2/